# events not firing when creating single instance of a view, but works when mutliple instance are created

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm a complete newbie to Backbone and am trying to get my head round few things. Im trying to build something using jQuery mobile and Backbone. Please find my code below

```
var WelcomePage = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function () {
            this.template = _.template($("#welcome_template").html());
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());

            return this;
        },

        events:{
            "click .btn_continue"   : function(){
                appRouter.navigate('login',{trigger: true});
            }
        }
    });

var Login = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function () {
            this.template = _.template($("#login_template").html());
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());

            return this;
        },

        events:{
            "click .btn_login"  : function(){
                appRouter.navigate('dashboard',{trigger: true});            
            }
        }
    });

var Dashboard = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function () {
            this.template = _.template($("#dashboard_template").html());
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());

            return this;
        },

        events:{
            "click .btn_loadImages" : function(){
                console.log('load Images');
            }
        }
    });


var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            "":"welcome",
            "login":"login",
            "dashboard":"dashboard",
        },

        initialize:function () {
        },

        welcome:function () {
            this.changePage(new WelcomePage());
        },

        login:function () {
            this.changePage(new Login());
        },

        dashboard:function(){
            this.changePage(new Dashboard());
        },

        changePage:function (page) {
            $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
            page.render();
            $('body').append($(page.el));


            $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: 'slide'});
        }

    });

    var appRouter = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

Now while I go back and forth through the screens using the BACK key the events fire OK using the code above. Then I tried replacing the code for the Router with the code below

```
    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes:{
                "":"welcome",
                "login":"login",
                "dashboard":"dashboard",
            },

            initialize:function () {
            },

            welcome:function () {
                this.changePage(v_WelcomePage);
            },

            login:function () {
                this.changePage(v_Login);
            },

            dashboard:function(){
                this.changePage(v_Dashboard);
            },

            changePage:function (page) {
                $(page.el).attr('data-role', 'page');
                page.render();
                $('body').append($(page.el));


                $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash:false, transition: 'slide'});
            }

        });

        var v_WelcomePage = new WelcomePage();
        var v_Login = new Login();
        var v_Dashboard = new Dashboard();

var appRouter = new Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
```

I noticed when I go back to the previous screens the events stop firing. Instead of creating the instance of the view in the action of the router I have created it outside and call it each time.I hope im making some sense.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are hooked up using jQuery when the view is instantiated, not rendered (in the Backbone View constructor function). jQuery disconnects those events when the html is removed from the page (probably in `$.mobile.changePage`).

So, the second time you render the page, the events will not be hooked back up. You could try calling `page.delegateEvents()` to manually hook up the events again, or you could re-create the view each time.

Comment: thanks Paul Hoenecke for your answer.When you suggest recreate the view each time,doesnt this mean more memory consumption? Thats the reason I tried creating it outside the Router hoping it wouldnt consume any more memory.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: page.delegateEvents() did the trick anyway,thanks for the answer !!